# Why can I read a dereferenced pointer, but can't write it in C, but can in C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, winapi

I needed to patch a program, so I made a dll that I can inject and on inject it patches one byte of the instruction. The code is pretty simple, the only thing that this time I wanted to write it in C, instead of C++, just of curiosity. But when I load my dll it's thread crashes in place of writing to that pointer. The pointer is 100% and works if you do it with WriteProcessMemory, but by some reason can't be written from a dll, directly from a process. The target executable is x86 and the dll is compiled with gcc. The compilation params look like this: gcc -shared mypatch.c -o mypatch.dll

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

void main()
{
    AllocConsole(); // Made a console so I can try to read the data, I thought maybe I was getting the wrong address, but I didn't.
    FILE* consoleFile;
    freopen_s(&consoleFile, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen_s(&consoleFile, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    freopen_s(&consoleFile, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    DWORD relAddr = 0x123456; // My address
    DWORD addr = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL) + relAddr; // Adress is relative to the main executable.
    printf("%X", *(byte*)(addr)); // Can read the real byte
    *(byte*)(addr) = 0x90; // Can't write, crash.
    printf("%X", *(byte*)(addr)); // Can't see, crashed.
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if(dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)main, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x70D41355 in SuperCoolApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x123456. occurred
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220471/discussion-on-question-by-electrosssnake-why-can-i-read-a-dereferenced-pointer).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing wasn't in the C or C++, it was about page protection. So the error was pretty descriptive at itself.

After this confusing try and pray sequence I've decided to look up my C++ code once again and I had found out that my original C++ code had VirtualProtect calls in the other file, which I surely haven't checked before asking. But although this is kind of a shit feeling that I've posted wrong info, I did learn that WriteProcessMemory ignores page protection, and also some tweaks to my C code, which was more of a C++ adaptation from my old code. Should've checked everything first twice. Very thankful to everyone, and kind of sorry.

Just as a confirmation note, everything works identically compared to C and C++. I've rewritten both versions from scratch and they behave totally the same, without the protection override they crash, and with override they both get the job done.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.